# MySQL: Using an Integer with Auto Increment as primary key - should I declare it as unsigned?

Tags: mysql, sql, integer, unsigned, unsigned-integer

When creating a table, I often use an `INTEGER` column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` as primary key (surrogate key), like so:

```
CREATE TABLE 'my_table' (
    user_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    […]
);
```

(Note that the ellipsis is only there to focus the example on whats important.)

Now I've read that `INTEGER` columns can hold an integer from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and from 0 to 4,294,967,295 when unsigned.

Since `user_id` will always be unsigned (MySQL starts counting from 0 if I am not mistaken), would it make sense to explicitly mark this column as `UNSIGNED` to allow more users stored in that table (4,294,967,295 instead of 2,147,483,647)?

Comment: Yes. If you ever have more than 2 billion users this will be relevant.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. If you ever get to the point where you're running up against the 2.1 billion user mark, you've probably already refactored this database.

Answer (score 2):

Unsigned allows for improvement in your queries based on that field.

Aside from that, there is no real difference

See the article at this link >> [Signed vs Unsigned](http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2010/08/25/mysql-unsigned-int-to-signed-int-performance-tips-index/) for more information as to why this is faster for queries.

---

Suppose the following query, where 'quantity' is the INT field.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE quantity <= 500
```

If `quantity` **IS NOT** unsigned, then and quantity field is an “int” and you have an index of this field, MySQL will define the range as -2147483648 to 500 and it will get the result based on this range.

However, if the `quantity` field **IS** unsigned, then that range will be 0 - 500.  A much smaller scope.

---

The only other convention that applies here is the actual storage of information. Unsigned since it's base is 0-4m, requires more storage as the binary count is higher. Where signed, is 0-2m with 1 bit to flag if it is positive or negative.  This results in a smaller storage requirement.

### SUMMARY

Use `Signed` if you want to save space.
Use `Unsigned` if you want speed.

Comment: That posting is spectacularly unconvincing.  Sounds like nonsense from someone who has a very poor understanding of how databases work.

Comment: Although the article is generally poorly written, the understanding of the difference between signed and unsigned integer's is clear. It just isn't explained as best possible (probably due to a language barrier). Signed uses a bit for flagging positive/negative and thus uses less space, however the query is factual. If you run that query on a signed field, it WILL search from -2m to 500,  something that doesn't require anything more than simple logic that query takes longer than 0-500.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html, the size of an UNSIGNED INT and a signed INT, so that won't make a difference in your choice.  As far as I know, AUTO_INCREMENT starts at 1, so if you think you will need more than 2,147,483,647 rows, go for the unsigned int.